# Fingerprint lost phone unlocking ability – where to troubleshoot?

Tags: lock-screens, 9.0-pie, fingerprint, samsung-galaxy-note-8

Recently, fingerprint sensor on my Note8 lost phone unlocking ability. How can I troubleshoot this?

Once the phone is unlocked, it still works normally: it...

- identifies already registered fingers (in fingerprint setup section)
- unlocks Samsung Pass
- pulls down and retracts the status bar (this works even in locked mode)

So far I...

- uninstalled all apps which were installed last week
- de-registered all fingerprints (what in turn disabled unlocking via reader) and registered them again
- checked the list of assistance apps, but all items are currently switched off

  - there were numerous device restarts during all these experiments – still no success

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in Knox Workspace, fingerprint reader got disabled by an event similar to a device security policy change which are issued by Knox Workspace administrator. This in turn disabled fingerprint unlock for the entire phone.

The solution was to detach Knox Workspace unlock procedure from phone unlock procedure by switching off the setting **Settings** > **Work Profile** > **Use one Lock** and by removal and re-adding fingerprints. Then the reader became available again for unlocking the phone although it is no more available for unlocking Knox Workspace.